# Find the product xy.

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

Given

$$
\log (x) + \frac{\log (xy^8)}{(\log x)^2+(\log y)^2} = 2\\
\log (y) + \frac{\log \left(\frac{x^8}{y}\right)}{(\log x)^2+(\log y)^2} = 0
$$

Find the product $xy$ if both $x$ and $y$ are real.

After applying basic log identities, I tried equating value of $ \large\frac{1}{(\log x)^2}+\frac{1}{(\log x)^2} $ but I am not getting any fruitful result.

Comment: you could try to add both expressions and simplify

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Already done that. Didn't get any benefit. The denominator term is creating problem.

Comment: yes, sorry, its of no use. Maybe, let $x=\mathrm e^{\xi}$ and $y=\mathrm e^{\psi}$?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform No. As the complexity of equations is still the same only the variables have changed.

Comment: numerical analysis shows that $xy=\mathrm e$ is a possible solution. There might exist more solutions though.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Actually base is 10 here and you are right answer is xy=10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hint put $\log(x)=a\,\log(y)=b$ this leads to two equations with two unknowns.

They are:

(I) $a+\frac{a+8b}{a^2+b^2}=2$ and

(II) $b+\frac{(8a-b)}{a^2+b^2}=0.$

Mutiplying (I) by $b$ and (II) by $a$ we get $ab+\frac{ab+8b^2}{a^2+b^2}=2b$ and $ab+\frac{8a^2-ab} {a^2+b^2}=0$, adding them up, we get $2ab+8=2b$ and $ab+4=b$ thus $a = \frac{b-4}{b}$. Solving equation (II) and substituting value for $a$ we have $b^3-\frac{16}{b} = 0$, thus $b=\pm 2$ thus $a=3,-1$ therefore $$(x , y) = \left(1000, \dfrac{1}{100}\right) || \left(\dfrac{1}{10} , 100\right)$$. Finally, we have, $$xy=10$$.

Comment: After $ ab+4=b $ how did you get a=b-4b?

Comment: some one edited wrongly lemme fix

Comment: oh my!! we were talking about $\log_{10}x$ all along?? i sometimes forget people do that...